# Form to get directions via Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'd like to create a HTML form integrating Google Maps so that users have to insert where they start their journey while the end of the trip is fixed (by me). They then hit the "Send" button and see on the same page (in a frame) the directions.

How would you proceed?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Directions Service API from google for this -

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests

Example - https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-simple

hop this helps